# Reverse Polarity Protection relay calculation

Tags: relay, safety, reverse-polarity

i want to make reverse polarity protection without voltage drop ,i was searching and i found this

https://www.edn.com/design/analog/4368527/Simple-reverse-polarity-protection-circuit-has-no-voltage-drop

[image]

now , **i want to size this relay** .

load ( 30 A , 48 V ) 1440 Watt

**Does load ( normally closed ) matters with relay?**

Where load is normally closed so relay is not operated when power supply is connected correctly.

so if that right then

**Does relay ( 12 V , 5 A ) 60 Watt  can do the work ?**

if all above right , then the load will taken into concern is when relay energized so the led ( in photo above ) and resistor here will be loads .

Thanks you .

Comment: Probably about the most ineffective reverse polarity protection in the entire world. What voltage does the relay need to operate? Say 9 volts - this means it won't protect until the reverse voltage is greater than 9 volts.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for your reply , yea you are right , here i have constant but remote power supply so it can be connected reverse but the value is 48 voltage , so it cant be less than 9 volts , actually i think it will be good if it doesnt drop any volts .

Comment: @Ahmedelmenshawie So wait, you're supplying a 12V relay with 48V? That's not going to protect from reverse voltage at all, reverse voltage will just first destroy the relay and then destroy whatever it was supposed to be protecting.

Comment: @Hearth oh  surely you are right , i was totally mistaken here , so if relay is  48 volt same as input here , then how about the load current if its more than the relay can endure

Comment: @Ahmedelmenshawie The relay needs to be rated for the load current. If you want to know if some particulars of this use case make it acceptable, you'll have to ask the manufacturer of the relay.

Comment: If the relay is 48 volts then it might not reverse protect until maybe -36 volts. Same as before, it's plain bad.

Comment: @Andyaka oh i got it , so even if my power supply is constant 48 , when reversed the time from zero to -36 or -48 is enough to burn the circuit

Comment: Probably very much so. You ought to comment on that crappy EDN site and point out the very poor level of thought that has gone into this engineering aberration.

Comment: @Andyaka i have to , thanks for your replys u really helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no.

You say your load requires 30 A, but your relay is only rated for 5 A. Relays are resilient and can handle a bit of pulsed overcurrent, but you're trying to use this relay for six times what it's rated for--it won't survive.

There are better reverse-polarity circuits out there, by the way. Relays are expensive, but a MOSFET is much less so.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but i have a question , how the relay will not consume power at correctly connected and in same time the current of load will burn it ?

Comment: @Ahmedelmenshawie I'm not sure what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: im not sure if i can but external links here , can u check this ?

Comment: https://www.edn.com/design/analog/4368527/Simple-reverse-polarity-protection-circuit-has-no-voltage-drop

Comment: @Ahmedelmenshawie As Andyaka points out, that won't protect from reverse voltages of less than 12V at all. (or at least, from reverse voltages less than what the relay's turn-on voltage is)

Comment: yea that an important point i noted it down , but im asking about the load current if it will burn the relay

Comment: @Ahmedelmenshawie The relay is not rated for more than 5 A. I don't know why specifically without looking at the datasheet. It's not a good idea to use components outside their rated conditions, anyway. I imagine it'll damage the contacts, though, over time; sure it's less voltage drop than a diode but it's still not *zero*. Nothing has zero voltage drop except superconductors.

Comment: well , so even if load connected to Normally closed , the on state resistor i'm limited with max current

Comment: @Ahmedelmenshawie I've never seen a relay that had different ratings for different contacts.

Comment: yea that's exactly what i want to know , thanks for your answers , it really helped me